# magento 2 minicart only loading on cart page

Tags: magento2

This is the minicart on cart page
[image: This is the minicart on cart page]

But on other pages its just this
[image: But on other pages its just this]

Could someone please suggest what could be going wrong.

It's a custom theme build on blank theme.

Comment: What is the exact magento2 version you are using?

Comment: Magento version 2.2.3